# Agile way to capitalize a word already written on iPhone iOS 15

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard, ipad

I'm trying to change the capitalization of a word I've already written selecting it and then pressing shift, but the prediction does not change to capitalized. Is there any new way to capitalize a word already written on iPhone in iOS 15?